# How does RootOfUnityQ work?

Tags: functions, complex, implementation-details, expression-test

How does Mathematica's [RootOfUnityQ](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RootOfUnityQ.html) function work?

That is, how does Mathematica know if a number is a root of unity?

**Example:**

Let $x = \frac{1-i \sqrt{2+\sqrt{5}}}{1+i \sqrt{2+\sqrt{5}}}$.

Then

```
In[1]:= RootOfUnityQ[x]
Out[1]= False
```

**Wrong Answers:**

This bahavior is not the same as

```
In[2]:= Reduce[Abs[x] == 1 && Simplify[Element[Arg[x]/(2 Pi), Rationals]]]
Out[2]= ArcTan[(2 Sqrt[2 + Sqrt[5]])/(1 + Sqrt[5])]/\[Pi] \[Element] Rationals
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how Mathematica does it, but we discussed some potential methods at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68159

Answer (score 6):

As long as we're giving methods that mimic the behavior, here is a quick implementation based on [Kronecker's theorem](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~chris/variations1905-4.pdf).

```
RoUQ[u_] :=
 If[! (Abs[N[u]] == 1), False,
  If[! AlgebraicIntegerQ[u], False,
   (f = MinimalPolynomial[u, x];
    n = Exponent[f, x];
    cf = CoefficientList[f, x]/Coefficient[f, x^n]; 
    M = Table[
      If[j == i + 1, 1,
       If[i == n, -cf[[j]], 0]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
    lambda = First[Eigenvalues[M, 1]];
    Abs[N[lambda]] == 1)]]
```

The sole reason for building the matrix $M$ is that `Eigenvalues[M,1]` is guaranteed to return the largest eigenvalue of $M$ (in absolute value), while I don't know how to tell `FindRoot` that it must give me the largest root.

---

J.M. below suggests just finding all the roots and taking the largest one. Based on a tiny amount of testing, I think that this is slower. Here is what I did:

```
(* Both methods will be tested on the same set of polynomials *)
data=Table[Sum[RandomInteger[100] x^j, {j,0,10}], {i,1,10^4}];

(* Find all roots and extract the largest *)
BigRoot1[f_]:=Max[Abs[x] /. NSolve[f==0,x]]

(* Find the largest eigenvalue of the companion matrix. *)
BigRoot2[f_]:=
(n = Exponent[f, x];
    cf = CoefficientList[f, x]/Coefficient[f, x^n]; 
    M = Table[
      If[j == i + 1, 1,
       If[i == n, -cf[[j]], 0.0]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
    lambda = First[Eigenvalues[M, 1]];
    N[Abs[lambda]])                                                               

Timing[Map[BigRoot1, data]][[1]]

10.9893

Timing[Map[BigRoot2, data]][[1]]

3.00254
```

I wouldn't take these results too seriously, because I'm sure both implementations do the list processing inefficiently, but it suggests that I'm not crazy to use `Eigenvalues[]`.

Comment: Well, you could use `x /. First @ Solve[p[x] == 0, x]` to generate the roots, and then `Pick[roots, #, Max[#]] &[Abs[roots]]` to get the largest of them all in magnitude. But using the companion matrix is cool anyway. :)

Comment: @J.M. It strikes me as wasteful to compute all those roots which will be discarded. I've added some tests above to support this claim.

Comment: Hmm, right. Then, I suppose if one wants to use `FindRoot[]`, there's always the option of trying to find the smallest root of $x^n p\left(\frac1{x}\right)$ and reciprocating that... the only reason I was somewhat lukewarm to using the companion matrix is that it looks uncomfortable to use $O(n^2)$ storage and $O(n^3)$ effort for just a single root...

Comment: @J.M. Yeah, memory usage is a good point. I guess the next question then is how often FindRoot[], starting at 0, fails to find the smallest root. A good first test would be `p[x]=x^10-x^9+x^7-x^6+x^5-x^4+x^3-x+1`, or perhaps this after the change of variable `x /. E^(2 Pi I RandomReal[]) x`. This has two roots at 0.85 and 1.176 and the other 8 are all on the unit circle with roughly equal spacing, so a random walk from 0 is very likely to hit one of the roots on the circle before the small root. I imagine FindRoot[] does something smarter than a random walk, though.

Answer (score 4):

If `Abs[x]==1` and `Element[Arg[x]/(2 Pi), Rationals]`, then the number is a root of unity

$$ \arg[x]= 2 \pi \frac{p}{q}$$
$p,q\in \mathbb{Z}$

and
$$ |x|=1 $$

$$ \to x^q=1 $$

because
$ |x^q|=|x|^q=1^q=1 $
and
$ \arg[x^q] = \arg[x] q = 2 \pi p $

So perhaps this mimics the behaviour

```
ru = TrueQ[Abs[#] == 1 && Simplify@Element[Arg[#]/(2 Pi), Rationals] ]&;
```

Comment: It does not mimic the behavior.  I updated the question to discuss your answer.

Comment: @TysonWilliams in your counterexample, it's just a matter of adding `TrueQ`. There are probably other counterexamples where this doesn't work, but please post them. I'm editing my answer

Comment: @R.M I am not looking for (numerically) approximate answers. I want to know with certainty.

Comment: Ok, suppose that this is the definition of `RootOfUnityQ`. The purpose of my question was to be able to verify Mathematica's answer for myself. So my question now becoems this: how does Mathematica compute `ArcTan[Sqrt[1/2 (1+Sqrt[5])]]/\[Pi]\[Element]Rationals`?